# slurm/sbatch doesn't work when option `-o` is specified

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I'm trying to run the following script with **sbatch** on our cluster.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o /SCRATCH-BIRD/users/lindenbaum-p/work/NEXTFLOW/work/chunkaa/work/a4/6d0605f453add1d97d609839cfd318/command.log
#SBATCH --no-requeue
#SBATCH  --partition=Bird 
set -e

echo "Hello" 1>&2
```

sbatch displays a job-id on stdout, there is nothing listed in `squeue` and it looks like nothing was written/executed.

If the line `#SBATCH -o /SCRATCH-BIRD/users/...`  is **removed** , then the script **works**.

the directory exists

```
$ test -w /SCRATCH-BIRD/users/lindenbaum-p/work/NEXTFLOW/work/chunkaa/work/a4/6d0605f453add1d97d609839cfd318/ && echo OK
OK
```

could it be a problem with the filesystem ? how can I test this ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it the partition is visible from the login node but not from the cluster nodes.